# Can't bind to 'dtOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I'm working to get angular way work and use this code https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

```
- node version:v6.10.3
- npm version:v6.10.3
- angular version:4.3.2
- jquery version:3.2.1
- datatables version:1.10.15
- angular-datatables version:4.2.0
- angular-cli version:1.2.6
```

I have made this steps to fix Unexpected value "DataTablesModule" imported by the module "AppModule". Please add a @NgModule Annotation.

```
 1-in tsconfig.json add
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
   "@angular/*": [
    "node_modules/@angular/*"
 ]
 2-in webpack.comon.js add 
  plugins: [
         new TsConfigPathsPlugin({
          configFileName: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),
          compiler: "typescript",
        })
   ]
```

but get this error

```
Can't bind to 'dtOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.
```

Can anyone help me please to fix this isuue?

Comment: did you find any working solution for above issue ?

Answer (score 23):

If you have `TablesComponent`, you should use this line in your `tables.module.ts` file:

```
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
```

And add `DataTablesModule` to `@NgModule` imports.

I had error when I add these lines in `appComponent`, but when I import in my special module, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

### Step 1 make sure that angular-dataTable it's installed.

$ ng add angular-dataTables

### Step 2 update this file angular-datatables.directive.d.ts

open this angular file node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.directive.d.ts

update this following line

```
static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<DataTableDirective, "[datatable],never,{dtOptions: {alias: "dtOptions"; required: false;}; dtTrigger: { alias: "dtTrigger"; required: false; }; }, {}, never, never, false, never>;
```

## Update it like this.

```
static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<DataTableDirective, "[datatable]",
        never,
        { dtOptions: 'dtOptions', dtTrigger: 'dtTrigger' },
        never,
        never,
        never,
        false,
        never>;
```

### Your HTML template

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

Comment: Bro, you're the goat
Could you explain please why that modification to the DataTableDirective file make it works?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Update ".angular-cli.json" file Styles and scripts properties as below.

```
{
 ........
  "apps": [
    { 
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        //for bootstrap4 theme
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        //for Datatable
        "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
        //for bootstrap4
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"
      ]
      ...
    }
  ],
 .....
}
```

Step 2. import DataTable Module in our Angular Application Module(Where you need.)

```
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
```

Below is the example of html table which is using DataTable -

```
<table id='table' datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

`import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';`

that's right ([Ganj Khani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4873251/ganj-khani)) import the `DataTablesModule`  into `app.module.ts` file and put it in

`@NgModule({ imports: [ CommonModule, DataTablesModule, MyRoutingModule ]`

It will work as expected and make sure you have all configured properly for the `dtOptions` in your respective `.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was quite simple fix. I forgot to add the `datatable` attribute to the table element. You must add that for the `DataTableModule` to pick it up.

**Example:**

```
<table datatable [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" [dtOptions]="dtOptions"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Upgrade Your Project with this command : 
 >ng update @angular/cli   @angular/core   --allow-dirty   --force

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer/customer.component';
import { DataTablesModule } from "angular-datatables";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'customer', component: CustomerComponent}
];

@NgModule({

  declarations: [

    CustomerComponent    ////without class declarations dataTable will not work....
  ],

  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), DataTablesModule, CommonModule],   //imports DataTablesModule here

  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: "Error Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments" will show when you imports  DataTablesModule if you don't upgrade your angular project. Angular 14 do not work....you need angular cli 15

Comment: Add 2 links in your index.html head section : <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: jquery.dataTables.min.js should add...<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>.it is very important

Answer (score 0):

Check the right module from you are importing:

> import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how you've structured your angular app (if you're have shared modules), you may need to import it using forRoot so it's a treated as a singleton service: `DataTablesModule.forRoot()`. This did the trick for me.